# Regex that matches with main route and filters but not matches with sub-routes

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core, razor

I have to make a Regular Expression on C# that matches with the following expressions:

> /videos/
>
> /videos?filter=some%filter
>
> /videos

But I need that this Regex does not match with expressions like:

> /videos/1
>
> /videos/67

For the moment I have the next code, but I do not really know how to complete the expression to make these matches with every word except numbers.

```
String currentUrl = Context.Request.Path.ToString() + Context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
String pageName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
Regex reg = new Regex(@"/(videos)(\/)?([^0-9])/g");

if (pageName == "Home")
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Partials/_LandingNavbarPartial");
}
else if (reg.IsMatch((currentUrl.ToLower())))
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Partials/_FilterNavbarPartial");
    @("Matches")
}
else
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Partials/_NavbarPartial");
    @("Not Matches")
}
```

I am interested in finish my regex expression: `/(videos)(\/)?([^0-9])/`

Comment: Try `Regex reg = new Regex(@"^/[^/]+/?$");`. Or, `@"^/videos(?:(?!/\d+$)[/?].*)?$"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After literally learn Regex from scratch, I have found the next expression:

```
(videos)\/*[^\d]*
```

Works as I mentioned that I wanted for.